# Swift Conform to Identifiable with existing property

Tags: swiftui, protocols, identifiable

I need to `ForEach` an array of structs, and so they each must conform to the `Identifiable` protocol. But since these structs are decoded from fetched JSON's, they already have an id property--the id used in my database. Should I give them another UUID to satisfy the `Identifiable` protocol? If not, how do I use an existing property as an id?

```
struct Event: Codable, Identifiable {
    let eventID: String
    let description: String
    let date: String
    let location: String
    let hostID: String
    let hostName: String

    // need?
    let id = UUID()
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use a computed property to return an existing property as the ID:

```
struct Event: Codable, Identifiable {
    let eventID: String
    //...other properties
    
    var id: String { eventID } //or whatever
}
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks!

Comment: does not computed id cause a memory leak in ForEach?